# What permissions do I need to update SiteCacheSettingsWriter with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, permissions, adfs, claims, output-cache

I'm trying to enable and configure output cache on a site collection with Powershell. But I get an Access denied when running the script.

> Exception calling "Update" with "0" argument(s): "Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"

I'm running the following script and it fails on $cacheSettings.Update():

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$cacheSettings = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.SiteCacheSettingsWriter("http://siteaddress")
$cacheSettings.EnableCache
$cacheSettings.EnableCache = $true
$cacheSettings.Update()
```

I'm runing the script with a user that I thought had all the necessary permissions but obviously not. I gave the user permissions with the following command:

```
Get-SPDatabase | Add-SPShellAdmin mydomain\user
```

I executed the Add-SPShellAdmin-command with my install-account without any errors. mydomain\user is also site collection administrator for http://siteaddress.

So, what permission am I missing to run the script?

Comment: Does this user have either Site Collection Administrator on the site you're setting the value on, or FullControl rights on the Web Application?

Comment: why not run the script under your install account.

Comment: I'm not running the script under my install account because I don't want to use it and want to have it disabled after recommendations from here: https://blog.lekman.com/2012/10/autospinstaller-prepare-server-hardware.html "Will be disabled after install is completed."

Comment: @TrevorSeward, I was convinced that I had Site Collection administrative rights, because an AD-group that I belong to was added to the "Site collection administrators" group. Now, several months later I came to realize that the AD-group added was the ADFS-claims-group. When I run scripts from the server I am running them as my windows claims-account. When I added the AD-group as windows claims-group in the Site collection administrators-group I was able to run the script.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was missing permissions on site collection administrative level. I had permission as site collection administrator when navigating from my local computer through adfs, i.e. with account c:0-.t|adfsfed|username@domain.com. But when running script from the server I'm running them as another user through integrated windows authentication, i.e. with account domain\username. I had to be site collection owner with the correct account to be able to run scripts towards the site collection. And I also needed permission through Add-SPShellAdmin.